# trying to reset labels with foreach

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

i have an app with a flow like the following

(vc1)pick items --> (vc2)user info --> (vc3)payment info --> done

when done im calling

```
[vc1 resetView];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in my vc1 my method looks like this

```
- (void) resetView {

for(UIStepper *stepper in steppers){
    stepper.value = 0;
}
[self updateCompleteSalesAmount];
}
```

if i call the method from within the vc1 it works fine, when i try to call it from vc3 the array is null and nothing happends.

any help or hint will be much appreciated :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: yeah sorry, i misclicked enter while typing so i posted an unfinished question

Comment: What is `steppers`, when is it modified? Why aren't you doing this on `viewWillAppear:`?

Comment: sorry, steppers is an array of UISteppers.

well i guess i should do that instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your `steppers` variable belongs to `vc1`.
In this case your `vc3` won't be able to access it.

You could try calling `[self resetView]` in `-(void)viewWillAppear` within `vc1`.

---

Another possible solution would be using notifications through `NSNotificationCenter`. This way your last VC could broadcast a notification about it being done.
Your `vc1` would subscribe to that notification and update itself accordingly. Read about it in [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/).

Comment: THANKS! you rock ;) will accept answer later when i can ;D